# The difference in how the builder where and codeigniter query builders work

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter, model

I work with several queries on Codeigniter.
When I use the code below the data return doesn't work.

```
    function check_dm($id_bidang) {
        $this->db->where("owner", $id_bidang);
        return $this->db->get("decision_maker");
    }
```

But when I use the code below, the data return works.

```
    function check_dm($id_bidang) {
        return $this->db->query("select * from decision_maker where owner ='$id_bidang'");
    }
```

Are there differences in the workings between the two codes above?

Comment: Have you performed a var_dump() or print_r() of each and compared the results to see the actual differences?

Comment: it should return the same - unfortunately a phrase like _doesn't work_ isn't really helpful - pls clarify your problem. the only thing i can imagine is that you have disabled the use of the query builder. Just take a look at your `database.php` in your config folder and check if the variable `$query_builder` is set to true.

Answer (score 2):

In your first method you are not returning any results. You are instead returning the DB object which holds various properties. To return the Result you should use

```
        $this->db->where("owner", $id_bidang);
        return $this->db->get("decision_maker")->row_array();
```

If your query returns multiple results, you should use `result_array()` instead of `row_array()`